# How can I close a BufferedReader after an exception happed?

Tags: java, exception

Take a simple code as an example:

```
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedReader dr = null;
            try{
                fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\acc_cp.log");
                dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                producer = new LogProducer(); // it may throw an exception
                String line = "";
                while((line = dr.readLine())!= null ){ // readline may throw an exception too
                     producer.send("test", line);
                     Thread.sleep(50);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(producer != null){
                    producer.close(); 
                }
            }
```

both `producer = new LogProducer();` and `(line = dr.readLine())` may throw exceptions. So ,my question is , if `producer = new LogProducer();` throw an exception, I want to close the BufferedReader properly, what's the appropriate approach?
If I put `dr.close()` in catch clause or finally clause, it forces me to throw an exception again,obviously this is not a good solution.

Comment: Use a [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that you are closing any resources that you've opened

Comment: To add to @MadProgrammer's comment, if you're using Java 6 or prior then use a silent `try-catch` in the `finally` section to close your resources.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the same way you currently close the `producer` (in the `finally` block) (and add a try-catch if you don't want to re-throw `IOException`) like

```
} finally {
    if(producer != null){
        producer.close(); 
    }
    if(dr != null) {
        try {
            dr.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you could use the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` like

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\acc_cp.log");
    BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    LogProducer producer = new LogProducer()) {
    // ...
```

Comment: `BufferedReader#close` throws `IOException`, thus the concern by OP about handling this exception in the `finally`.